# earliest_timestamp is below latest_timestamp in postman test

Tags: get, timestamp, postman, typeerror

im  trying to create test script for condition `earlier_timestamp` is below that `latest_timestamp`

```
var moment = require('moment');

pm.test("Condition - Earliest Timestamp is < 1 day", function() {

    var latest_Timestamp = pm.response.json();
    var earliest_Timestamp = pm.response.json();
  
    pm.expect(pm.earliest_timestamp.get(earliest_timestamp)).to.be.below(pm.latest_timestamp.get(latest_timestamp));
});
```

Im getting response

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: Please show us your response body. Also `pm.earliest_timestamp.get(earliest_timestamp)` is not gonna work. And there's an issue with opening/ closing bracket in your pm.expect...

Comment: Hi @ChristianBaumann, thank you for the response. 

Response body has 
"latest_timestamp": "2022-03-18 13:01:14.619542+00:00",
 "earliest_timestamp": "2022-03-17 13:01:14.619542+00:00",

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Please edit the question to include the full response. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following response body:

```
{
   "latest_timestamp":"2022-03-18 13:01:14.619542+00:00",
   "earliest_timestamp":"2022-03-17 13:01:14.619542+00:00"
}
```

this will work:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

var latest = Date.parse(jsonData.latest_timestamp);
var earliest = Date.parse(jsonData.earliest_timestamp);

pm.test("Condition - Earliest Timestamp is < 1 day", function() {

    pm.expect(latest).to.be.above(earliest);

});
```

Depending on your actual response body, you would need to adapt lines 3 & 4 a little bit.